# How can i get value of input from checkbox with multiple selects?

Tags: php, smarty, html-select

I have a script where I use PHP with Smarty. I only want to rescue a variable through a multiple checkbox with values with several options of selects. How do I do this?

Below is the current structure, but it does not bring the values ​​of the selects when I click the checkbox of `name = "orcar"`

```
{foreach from=$planes item=plane}
<tr>
<td><label class="checkbox"><i class="icon icon-hand-right"></i>                
<input name="orcar" type="checkbox"/></td></label>                                  
<td><select class="input-medium"><option>{$plane.model}</option></select></td>
<td><select class="input-large">
  <option>{$anv1}</option>
  <option>{$anv2}</option>
  <option>{$anv3}</option>
  <option>{$anv4}</option>                  
</select></td>
<td><select class="input-medium">
  <option>{$eng1}</option>
  <option>{$eng2}</option>
  <option>{$eng3}</option>
  <option>{$eng4}</option>          
</select></td>                                  
</tr>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select elements don't have `name` properties.  You need these in order to POST the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's true, your inputs have no name. 
Second point if you put the same name to two different inputs you'll get an array with the answer.

Comment: if any of this comments has solved your problem please accept it as correct, so any other person with the same problem will find the answer easily